# Hibernate Batch Processing insert 1000000 records

Tags: java, hibernate, batch-processing

When I am trying to insert 1000000 records in MySQL DB, I really have only 1000. What is wrong?

1. This is my hibernate.cfg.xml

   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/hibernatedb
   root
   bervol13

   1

   50

   org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

   thread

   org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property> -->

   false
   org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider

   true

   update
2. This is my Student:

   ```
   package ua.berchik.vovchuk.dto;
   ```

   import java.io.Serializable;

   import javax.persistence.Cacheable;
   import javax.persistence.Column;
   import javax.persistence.Entity;
   import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
   import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
   import javax.persistence.Id;
   import javax.persistence.Table;

   import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
   import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

   @Cacheable
   @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
   @Entity
   @Table(name="STUDENT")
   public class Student implements Serializable {

   ```
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -6853928080190944025L;

   @Id
   @Column(name="ID")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   private int id;
   @Column(name="STUDENT_NAME")
   private String studName;
   @Column(name="ROLE_NUMBER")
   private int rollNumb;
   @Column(name="COURSE")
   private String course;

   public Student(){}

   public Student(String studName, int rollNumb, String course) {
       super();
       this.studName = studName;
       this.rollNumb = rollNumb;
       this.course = course;
   }
   public int getId() {
       return id;
   }
   public void setId(int id) {
       this.id = id;
   }
   public String getStudName() {
       return studName;
   }
   public void setStudName(String studName) {
       this.studName = studName;
   }
   public int getRollNumb() {
       return rollNumb;
   }
   public void setRollNumb(int rollNumb) {
       this.rollNumb = rollNumb;
   }
   public String getCourse() {
       return course;
   }
   public void setCourse(String course) {
       this.course = course;
   }

   public String toString()  
    {  
     return "Id: "+this.id+" ROLL Number: "+this.rollNumb+"| Name: "+this.studName+"| Course: "+this.course;  
    }
   ```

   }
3. This is my HibernateUtil:

   ```
   package ua.berchik.vovchuk.hibernate.util;
   ```

   import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
   import org.hibernate.annotations.common.annotationfactory.AnnotationFactory;
   import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

   public class HibernateUtil {

   ```
   private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   static{
       try{
           sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
       } catch(Throwable th){
           System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed"+th);
           throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(th);
       }
   }

   public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
       return sessionFactory;
   }
   ```

   }
4. And this is my Main:

   package ua.berchik.vovchuk.hibernate;

   ```
   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.Map;

   import javax.xml.crypto.Data;

   import org.hibernate.Criteria;
   import org.hibernate.Query;
   import org.hibernate.Session;
   import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
   import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
   import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;

   import ua.berchik.vovchuk.dto.FourWheeler;
   import ua.berchik.vovchuk.dto.Student;
   import ua.berchik.vovchuk.dto.TwoWheeler;
   import ua.berchik.vovchuk.dto.User;
   import ua.berchik.vovchuk.dto.UserDetails;
   import ua.berchik.vovchuk.dto.Vehicle;
   import ua.berchik.vovchuk.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil;

   public class HiernateTest {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

           SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
           Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
           session.beginTransaction();

           for ( int i=0; i<1000000; i++ )  
           {  
               Student student = new Student("Name "+i, i, "Course "+i);  
               session.save(student); 
               if(i%50 == 0){
                   session.flush();
                   session.clear();
               }
           }  

           session.getTransaction().commit();
           session.close();
       }

   }
   ```